# What is Webstorm's PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE?

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Shows up in `codeStyleSettings.xml`.

```
<option name="PREFERRED_PROJECT_CODE_STYLE" value="Default (1)" />
```

It doesn't appear in [code style xml](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/code-style-xml.html)'s documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the 'Scheme' option - if the global scheme is being chosen (any scheme except for the 'project' one), it's written this way to project `codeStyleSettings.xml`